# ¿Cómo graficar una PCA bubble plot?

Tags: r

He hecho una PCA, pero he intentado sin éxito que los puntos estén en formato "bubbleplot", donde el tamaño del punto varíe según el valor de una variable.

Aquí está mi código:

```
library("FactoMineR")
library(factoextra)
ulva<-c(1,1,0,2,3,2)
sediment<-c(1,1,1,3,3,4)
deep<-c(3,3,2,1,1,1)
site<-c("CH","CH","CH","AA","AA","AA")
ulva2<-c("1","1","0","2","3","2")
data<-data.frame(site,sediment,deep,ulva2)
#Then I perform the PCA
s.pca <- PCA(data[,2:3], graph = FALSE)
#Grafico:
a<-fviz_pca_biplot(s.pca, repel = TRUE, # Variables color
                col.ind = "#00FF00",  # Individuals color
                pointsize=ulva2,fill.ind = "#00FF00",
                pointshape = 21, 
                )
a
```

El problema es que no puedo cambiar el título "sizepoint", me gustaría que pusiera "Ulva" en vez de "sizepoint". Además, me gustaría escribir el sitio (AA or CH) en el punto, y no el número de la muestra. Adjunto una imagen de Terradas et al., 2019 que muestra más o menos lo que me gustaría hacer (ese gráfico se realizó con Primer).

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias!
[image: bubbleplot PCO]

Comment: Hola. Estás en el sitio en español, así que todo va en español. Puedes [edit] y traducir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un `fviz_pca_biplot()` no deja de ser un gráfico `ggplot` estándar por lo que se le pueden aplicar los mismos métodos. En primer lugar, el titulo del tamaño del punto se puede modificar, entre otras formas, mediante `labs(size = "ulva")` que modifica la etiqueta para la dimensión `size` del gráfico. Para modificar las etiquetas de los puntos, en vez de modificarlas realmente, podrías no dibujarlas y hacerlo con un `geom_text()`, para esto deberías construir un nuevo `dataframe` a partir del objeto `PCA` para obtener las coordenadas de cada punto y agregarle a este la etiqueta deseada:

```
puntos <- as.data.frame(s.pca$ind$coord)
puntos$label <- site
puntos

       Dim.1      Dim.2 label
1 -1.5990451  0.2392449    CH
2 -1.5990451  0.2392449    CH
3 -0.8112065 -0.5485937    CH
4  1.1421751 -0.1708892    AA
5  1.1421751 -0.1708892    AA
6  1.7249466  0.4118823    AA
```

Y el gráfico sería:

```
a <- fviz_pca_biplot(s.pca, 
                repel = TRUE, 
                col.ind = "#00FF00",
                pointsize = ulva,
                geom.ind = 'point',
                fill.ind = "#00FF00",
                pointshape = 21)

a +
  labs(size = "ulva") + 
  geom_text(data = puntos,
            aes(x = Dim.1, y = Dim.2, label = label), 
            hjust = -.5, 
            vjust = -.1)
```

Nota: Debería ser `pointsize = ulva` y no `ulva2` que es un vector de caracteres.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]